# Web Published App Script HTML Service/JQueryUI App doesnt work. Dev version does

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script

I've made a simple JQUERY UI Datepicker App using HTML Service just to see how things work.
It has a textbox which shows datepicker when clicked and a localisation selector next to it.
When I execute it from developer link, it works although very very slow.

But when I try to execute same app from web publish link, which is different from Dev link, It doesn't work.
It shows the text box, but not the listbox which lets you select localisation. Also it doesn't show datepicker when clicked.

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet() {

Logger.log(getContent("jquidatepickerFR"));
Logger.log(getContent("jquidatepickerTR"));
var result=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myPage').evaluate();
  Logger.log(result.getContent());  
return result;
}

function getContent(filename) {

var return1= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getRawContent();
return return1;
}
```

**myPage.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Localize calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <?!= getContent("jquidatepickerTR")?>
  <?!= getContent("jquidatepickerFR")?>
  <?!= getContent("style")?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "tr" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />&nbsp;
  <select id="locale">
    <option value="tr"  selected="selected">Türkçe</option>
    <option value="fr">French (Français)</option>
  </select></p>


</body>
</html>
```

[Public Web App Link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwL8ztpdngWDaLpvCeAZvlwo94aGowa6MIVNyWgw9ovxixqWIR6/exec)

What causes this, does anybody have any idea?

Comment: "Cannot emulate complex event handler div onchange="t" in ES5/3 mode". BTW, what's up with the encoding?

Comment: What encoding? It's supposed to be UTF-8 by default...at least that's what I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, I think (but I don't understand it...). It is a Caja problem.

https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1645